# how to create a wifi hotspot

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I use internet on my desktop, and I use a internet receiver (WiMAX UH235) connected through a USB cable and it's not a wireless machine! I also have a TP-Link Router (TL-WR340G) that is connected to my desktop using a network cable. My question is:

Can I make WiFi from my WIMAX to my ROUTER so I can connect other machines like my iPhone and laptop or that can not be done? and if it can be done, could you please tell me how to make it? I tried sharing but it didn't work! :/

Comment: You can always route through your laptop, but you know they have off-the-shelf routers these days with USB ports that you can plug your WiMAX adapter into.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest/fastet yet very functional method I have seen is an small program named AP-HotSpot (https://github.com/hotice/AP-Hotspot), open source and free, running under Linux, but your WiFi card must admit AP (access point) mode (most actually do). The download is here:

https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+packages

(choose the package named "ap-hotspot", there are versions for latest Ubuntu versions)

Installation for Debian (I have used the .deb package for Ubuntu 13.10 and it worked at Kali Linux fine) is as simple as:
1.- Installing needed (main program depends of) packages:

```
# apt-get install dnsmasq hostapd install libnotify-bin
```

2.- Downloading latest version:

```
$ wget https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/webupd8/+files/ap-hotspot_0.2.1-1~webupd8~1_all.deb
# dpkg -i ap-hotspot_0.2.1-1~webupd8~1_all.deb
```

3.- Repair unsolved dependencies (it happent to me):

```
# apt-get install -f
```

4.- Execute it using (requires GUI, not working on text console), and will ask you a few simple questions about configuration:

```
# ap-hotspot configure
# ap-hotspot start
```

5.- To stop it:

```
# ap-hotspot stop
```

Note: remember that "$" means "execute as unpriviledged user", and "#" means "execute as root user".

Comment: am sorry dude i didn't mention that i have windows 7

Comment: Then I suggest for you to edit your post (even the tittle). It will help others to give you exactly the help you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for something as simple as possible and running under Windows, I suggest [Virtual Router](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) from Chris Pietschmann. It is open source. Not very configurable, but it is difficult to find something more easy to manage.